# How do i get the right output?

Tags: c

so the program works except for one part of it.

I really dont understand why its not outputting the correct thing. Also i have to use the strtok, strcmp, and fgets functions. So i cant change those.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main(){

 char a[256];

 while(x==0){//this will loop until the exit cammand is given

 int y = (strcmp(fgets(a, 256, stdin), "exit\n")); 
 char* token = strtok(a, " ");
 int numOfTokens = 0;

 if (y == 0){
 exit(0);
 }
 else{
 printf("Line read:%s\n", a);
 printf("Token(s):");
 while(token != NULL){
 numOfTokens +=1;
 printf("\n%s", token);
 token= strtok(NULL, " ");
 }
 printf("%i token(s) read\n", numOfTokens);
 }
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

So everything is entered from a linux terminal. the output should be:

```
 `h e l l o//input
 //output as followed
 Line read:h e l l o
 Token(s):
 h
 e
 l
 l
 o
 5 token(s) are read`
```

but when i do the thing that messes up is:`Line read:h`
how would i make it where it prints the whole line that the user inputs

Comment: Please indent your code - it's all but unreadable.

Comment: @pmg after which print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move `strtok()` to after the `printf()`.
Reason is that `strtok()` changes its argument so you print the changes.

instead of

```
... strtok(a, " ") ... ;
... printf("%s", a) ... ;
```

do

```
... printf("%s", a) ... ;
... strtok(a, " ") ... ;
```

Comment: thank you for your help.